# Identifying the relationship between Entities

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

I am trying to learning Database Design and trying to identify the relationship between entities.

For example `Stores` and `Items` have many-to-many relation as a store have many items and an item is sold at many different stores.

And `items` and `reviews` have one-to-many relation. now I want to identify the relation between a `store` and a `review`. How should I understand/identify such kind of relationships?

Comment: Is the review for the `store` _or_ the `item`?

Comment: The relationship is between `items` and `reviews`.  I don't understand the question.  There appears to be no direct relationship.

Comment: It's normal now as if one product is sold on one store it review are displayed in all stores